# What is Dev Mode? And how can I use it?

Tags: pallet, storage, weight, benchmarking, maxencodedlen

I heard there is something called Dev Mode in Substrate for pallet development.

What is Dev Mode? And how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

[Dev Mode](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#dev-mode-palletdev_mode) is for developer-friendliness for ease of pallet development and rapidly testing core business logic before cementing it in with proper benchmarking and bounding storage.

> Not to be used for production!

One can enable a pallet with [Dev Mode](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#dev-mode-palletdev_mode) by making the following change in their pallet's `lib.rs` file:

```rust
- #[frame_support::pallet]
+ #[frame_support::pallet(dev_mode)]
```

With Dev Mode enabled you can have a weight of zero i.e. `#[pallet::weight(0)]` and you do not have to `MaxEncodedLen` on storage types.

Read the fulls docs on Dev Mode:

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#dev-mode-pallet

Dev Mode was also first covered in the Polkadot Release Analysis v0.9.33:

- https://forum.polkadot.network/t/polkadot-release-analysis-v0-9-33/1287#add-dev-mode-palletdev_mode-12