# #[frame_support::pallet(dev_mode)] versus #[frame_support::pallet]

Tags: pallet, dev

I see that most of the pallets are annotated as `#[frame_support::pallet]`, but some of them are `#[frame_support::pallet(dev_mode)]` and my question is what exactly means `dev-mode` in the context of the annotation/pallet? Does it (in any way) help for delivering source code of a pallet?

To answer that question, I was looking at [the documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/) and was looking at Substrate code per se, but did not found exact answer. Of course, I have some guesses, but only empty guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying pallet(dev_mode) allows you to place the pallet in *development mode*, you should only see it in pallets that are under development.

It relaxes a number of constraints, provides defaults for a number of things that are not super relevant when a pallet is under construction (including weights), and disables accidental production compilation of the pallet.

Bruno made a great explanation in this previous Stackexchange answer: [What is Dev Mode? And how can I use it?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/8010/2762).

And here you can see PR where it was introduce: [Add pallet dev mode](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12536)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to dev mode: https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#dev-mode-palletdev_mode